# Error install QGIS 3.0 at Ubuntu 16.04 - Dependent packages

Tags: ubuntu, qgis

I installed QGIS 2.18 at ubuntu 16.04 following [these tutorial](http://www.processamentodigital.com.br/2017/03/30/qgis-instalacao-da-versao-2-18-5-no-ubuntu-16-04-lts/).

When I launched it, a message of upgrade appears to me.

I uninstalled QGIS 2.18 to make an upgrade to version 3.0. To do this, I executed the steps of [this link](https://www.howtoinstall.co/pt/ubuntu/xenial/qgis?action=remove).

But, when I tried to install these new version, following [this another site](https://scriptndebug.wordpress.com/2018/02/27/installing-qgis-3-on-ubuntu-16-04/), I got the following message of error:

```
lucas@lucas:~$ sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass saga
[sudo] password for lucas: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-qgis : Depends: python-qgis-common (= 1:3.0.1+git20180411+dabf1c7+24xenial-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqgispython3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqgis-analysis3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqgis-core3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqgis-gui3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqgis-server3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
 qgis : Depends: gdal-abi-2-2-2 but it is not installable
        Depends: libgdal20 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis-analysis3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-app3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-core3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-gui3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.0.1+git20180411+dabf1c7+24xenial-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:3.0.1+git20180411+dabf1c7+24xenial-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgdal20 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libqgis-app3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgis-core3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgis-gui3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgisgrass7-3.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: grass740 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help will be apreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Possible to temporarily toggle your system's language to English and re-post the error? SO works best if everyone uses English.

Comment: Thank you @CollinM.Barrett, done.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been over 2 years but I'll post what it worked for me in case anyone else finds this question.
Looks like `aptitude` handles the dependencies better, so I ran:

```
$ sudo aptitude install qgis
```

Important to note, the first option it gave me was:

```
     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     python3-psycopg2 [Not Installed]                   
2)     python3-qgis [Not Installed]                       
3)     qgis [Not Installed]                               
4)     qgis-plugin-grass [Not Installed]                  



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
```

I chose `n` because  the solution of keeping those packages uninstalled doesn't solve my situation, then it prompted:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:     
1)     python3-psycopg2 [2.8.4-2 (focal)]
```

And that's when I hit `y` because installing that dependency is the solution I needed.
I'd suggest trying with `aptitude` but being wary that it doesn't magically solve the problem, and you have to pay attention and choose the right path to take.